# Java reflection not modifying my @Named bean variables

Tags: java, reflection, ejb, named

I know shouldn't use reflection, but this is a temporary solution until ...

I have 1:

```
@Named("PoiBean")
@SessionScoped
public class PoiBean implements ActionContext, Serializable {
   private String name = "www";

   @EJB
   private NavigationServiceRemote nav;

@PostConstruct
private void testReflection() {
    try {
        nav.TestMe(this);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PoiBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PoiBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PoiBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PoiBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void prepareListAllForm() {
    this.setName("test me");
    }
}
```

I have 2:

```
@Stateless(mappedName="NavigationService")
public class NavigationServiceBean implements NavigationServiceRemote, NavigationContext {
    @Override
     public void TestMe(ActionContext ctx) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException { 

        Method method = ctx.getClass().getMethod("prepareListAllForm", new Class[] {});
        method.invoke(ctx, new Object[] {});
      }
```

Explains: when PoiBean starts, EJB nav is injected, after that in @PostConstruct I call test method TestMe.

When I debug, before Test me name=www, inside PoiBean::prepareListAllForm (called by reflection), name variable is modified = "test me", and after return the name returns to www.

Is like reflection calls prepareListAllForm on a copy of PoiBean ...

What I am trying to achieve now is to modify that variable using prepareListAllForm function, called using reflection from an @EJB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is NavigationServiceRemote annotated @Remote?  Remote invocation of an EJB interface will marshall/unmarshall the arguments and return values, so the TestMe method will receive a copy of PoiBean.  You will need to use a local EJB if you want to modify the instance.

Comment: Yes indeed is marked as remote interface. This is a sign I should read more. Tnx for your reply!

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you should "accept" it to improve your rating (and mine!).

Comment: I did now, Sorry my first time on this website and didn't know how it works.